# Добавить маркеры на карту google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Хочу добавить маркеры выбранных станций метро (массив arr_metro) и маркеры квартир (массив array_coordinates), если первыми добавлять маркеры метро то маркеры квартир не добавляются и наоборот:( В чем проблема?

```
function initMap(array_coordinates, array_marker_info, arr_metro) {
var map;
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), {
    center: {lat: 55.7522200, lng: 37.6155600},
    zoom: 12,
    scrollwheel: false
});
var metro = [];
var col_metro = arr_metro.length;
for(var i = 0; i <= col_metro; i++) {
    var ll = arr_metro[q].split(',');
    var lng = ll[1];
    if(lng.search(';') != -1) {
        lng = lng.replace(';', '');
    }
    var coordinates_metro = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], lng);
        metro[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:coordinates_metro,
        map: map,
        title: "Метро",
        visible: true,
        icon: 'images/metro_flag.png'
    });
}
var markers = [];
var infowindow = [];
var col = array_coordinates.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: array_marker_info[i]
    });
    var ll = array_coordinates[i].split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latlng,
        map: map,
        title: array_coordinates[i],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        visible: true,
        icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    });
    setInfoWindowHandlers(i);
}

function setInfoWindowHandlers(i) {
    markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
        console.log(i);
        infowindow[i].open(map, markers[i]);
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вообще на карте что-нибудь появляется? По идее, не должно, потому что:

> ReferenceError: q is not defined
>
> for(var i = 0; q <= col_metro; i++) {

Что такое q? Должно быть i. Почему <=? Должно быть <.

> for (var i = 0; i <= col; i++) {

Аналогично. i < col

Comment: Там I! q - опечатка! Потому что array_coordinates - это массив с координатами, а col - количество координат в массиве! Что Вас смущает? В вопросе написано, появляется или нет!